# Set the instance to null not the variable referencing it

Tags: c#, reference, null

I created an object, and I assigned it to two variables found in separate classes.

If in one class I set the variable to null, it only breaks that reference to the object but the object itself still persists due to the other reference.

How do I set the object to null, so that both references point to null? Without finding every reference.

this is pseudocode. The idea is to lose the reference in both ClassA (ref1) and ClassB (ref2).

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassC ref1 = new ClassC ();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ref1 = null;
    }

}

public class ClassB
{
    public static ClassC ref2;

    public static AssignC (ClassC c)
    {
        ref2 = c;
    }

}

public class ClassC
{

    public ClassC ()
    {
        ClassB.AssignC (this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show a code sample?

Comment: What's the problem this is trying to solve?

Comment: create another object encapsulating the existing one.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think he is trying to remove all instances of a created class, no matter who is currently referencing it.

Comment: Maybe [weak references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247(v=vs.110).aspx) will help, not sure enough, because you didn't gave a deep description of the problem

Comment: Could you share some code

Comment: @qxg: Still you won't loose all references to the inner class if there (think of event handlers attached, etc.)

Comment: If 2 class objects hold a reference to the same member, trying to clear it from 1 of them breaks the encapsulation paradigm. The second object is not aware, that its member has been nulled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I understand its not standard practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You cannot reach into the internals of another class, (well, not conventionally.) This form of **Encapsulation** makes .Net code much easier to debug.

You could write a function on the class that sets all its members to `null`, you could do this as an implementation of `IDisposable`.

When there are no references to an object the Garbage Collector will reclaim the memory, you cannot directly control this.

---

You could rewrite your example like this.

```
public class A
{
    private C c = new C();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        c.Dispose();
        c = null;
    }
}

public static class B
{
    private static C c;

    public static LastC
    {
        get
        {
            return c;
        }

        set
        {
           c = value;
        }
    }
}

public class C : IDisposable
{       
    public C()
    {
        B.C = this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (B.LastC == this)
        {
            // LastC has not been set by another instance.
            B.LastC = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll note that I've made the static reference accessible via a setter, so that other classes can access it.

Answer (score 2):

Setting null to reference-type variable change only VALUE of that particular variable - reference to object. Good article by Jon Skeet - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

In your case its better to wrap object into Singleton pattern. So the setting of null to main variable will destroy the only reference to object and it can be garbage-collected.

Comment: Who is this Jon Skit? ;p

Answer (score 2):

It is simply not possible.

*References* can be either `null` or point to an actual instance. When you assign, as in `ref2 = c;` the value of one reference is *copied* to another reference. After that you have two references to the same instance. (The instance is not copied, for sure, only the reference; these are reference types.)

When you do `ref1 = null;` that just overwrites the particular reference with one that points to "nothing". It doesn't destroy any instance, just makes a single reference "point" to something else. Other references are unaffected (method parameters with `ref` or `out` of currently executing methods could in fact be the *same reference*, the one which is turned to points elsewhere).

In the question title you say "set the instance to null", but that doesn't really make sense, because an instance is an object (not a reference).

So how to destroy an instance? *You can't.* The garbage collector might come by at some point (when you are about to allocate a new object) and see that some instances have zero references to them. It will then remove the instances from memory.

You can't "zero" other people's references. Just because you have one references to an instance, there is no way to say "search through the entire application and find other references that happen to point to the same instance right now, and change all those references. That would be a really terrible thing to allow, because people could never be sure when their variables changed out of nowhere.

Comment: Thanks this was a great response!